# Is picking up energy instant?

Tags: screeps

Is it instant to pick up any amount of energy from dropped enemy creeps?

If it isn't I doubt how efficient it would be to not only program my creeps to pick it up but cost efficient having a creep who's job it is to only pick up loose energy.

Comment: What game are you talking about?

Comment: @anders screeps... It's in the tags

Answer (score 1):

Yes transferring energy happens in 1 tick but mining energy depends on how many work modules you have.